# How to create parent and child row in a grid in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I need to create a grid that seperate the parent and child rows. What I am doing here, just iterate the array list and fetch out the objects. Again in the last position of object I have  an arraylist that I need to iterate for the child rows. so please guide me how I do this in my jsp.

e.g.

```
 <TH1> <TH2> <TH3>

 <TRP1-1> <TRP1-2> <TRP1-3>
    <TRC1-1> <TRC1-2> <TRC1-3>
    <TRC2-1> <TRC2-2> <TRC2-3>

 <TRP2-1> <TRP2-2> <TRP2-3>
    <TRC2-1> <TRC1-2> <TRC1-3>
    <TRC2-1> <TRC2-2> <TRC2-3>
```

Above example is the format of the table. where TH is the heading of the table
TRP is the parent row and TRC is the child row.

```
 <%
   for(int iCtr=0;iCtr<arryListObj.size();iCtr++)
   {
      Object[] objVal=(Object[])arryListObj.get(iCtr);
      ArrayList arryListV=(ArrayList)=objVal[12];
 %>
       <tr>
          <td ><%= String.valueOf(objVal[0])%></td>
          <td ><%= String.valueOf(objVal[0])%></td>
          <td ><%= String.valueOf(objVal[0])%></td>
       </tr>
<%    for(int iVal=0;iVal<arryListV.size();iVal++)
      {
         Object[] objChildVal=(Object[])arryListV.get(iVal);
 %>
       <tr>
          <td ><%= String.valueOf(objChildVal[0])%></td>
          <td ><%= String.valueOf(objChildVal[0])%></td>
          <td ><%= String.valueOf(objChildVal[0])%></td>
       </tr>
 <%
      }
   }
 %>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried as JSP code? It helps us help you.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I added the code in my question.